# Date Format Problems in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, date-format, sql-insert

I have a problem using the Date form I have in `JDateChooser`. I'm using the `YYY-MM-dd` format and it won't insert into my Oracle 10g database. It gives me a `java.sql.SQLDataException` error:

> ORA-01841: L'année (complète) doit être comprise entre -4713 et +9999
>   et être différente de 0

Comment: Please provide sample of code showing how insert implemented

Comment: Is date format `YYY-MM-dd` or `YYYY-MM-dd`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample

select to_date(sysdate,'YYYY-MON-DD') from Daul;

Regards.